# Meaning of 真顔がもう冗談

Tags: meaning

> 「僕はあまり冗談は言わないよ」
>
> 「あっはー。その**真顔が、もう冗談**だよね」

Based on context I assume he said the first line with a serious face (based on her reply), but I'm not quite sure how to interpret what she means by his straight face / serious look being a joke.

Comment: If it helps, this is pretty similar to「冗談は顔だけにしろ」and the like. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39527/26484

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more context but I'd guess either of the following:
a.) There is something hilarious he had said previously with his straight face, making it even more hilarious.
b.) The fact that he always has a straight face is ridiculous. (Could be said in a mean way, like "I'm not joking" "Yeah? Well, your face is a joke!!")